# Why is the normal force of a rope on a pulley, not considered while analyzing the free body diagram of pulley?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

Suppose an inextensible massless rope is placed on a pulley surface. Obviously there will be a normal force between the pulley and rope, right?

**Why is the normal force of rope on the pulley ($N_{pulley,rope}$) not considered while analyzing the free body diagram of pulley?**

[image]

I have added a picture showing where I was confused. Fig I shows the free body diagram of Pulley A.

[image]

[Link for the video:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeTsZhYHY_E&list=PLUl4u3cNGP61qDex7XslwNJ-xxxEFzMNV&index=49)

Comment: The pulley and rope are considered to be perfect. That is there is no friction between the contact points of the pulley and rope . The rope is massless so it cannot have any weight of its own . This might seem weird at first but thats how an introduction is given in NLM. Once the basic concept is understood , you will find problems where you have to consider the mass of the rope

Comment: What is NLM? Can you explain?

Comment: Are you deducing Normal force is zero? From the fact that Friction is zero. Since. $f_{static}=\mu N_{rope, pulley}=0\implies N_{rope, pulley}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He didn't considered normal force since the rope and pulley are massless . So there is no weight of rope (mg pulling the rope or the pulley).

In real life you are correct , there is a normal force between the rope and pulley.

Comment: But then, How he consider tension? Normal force is nothing to do with the weight. right? It is generated due to molecular level repultion. right?

Comment: Tension is not due to the rope's weight.It's due to that man pulling the rope.

Comment: Thank you. Now,this lead me one more question. Why $T_1$ is directed upward in the figure 1?

Comment: Does the pulley has any role in generating tension?

Comment: I am confused with these questions. please help me.

Comment: @Unknownx I have been there where u r .

Comment: No pulley doesn't play any role in generating tension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110780/discussion-between-ohw-and-unknown-x).